# Duvida em fazer um Json

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

Olá, tenho o seguinte Json.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria de mostrar o valorTotal em um 'p', estou usando o datatables para mostrar os valores do "data". Estou usando o https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html como exemplo. E para montar a tabela eu uso(apenas um exemplo, a minha está igual só com os dados que eu desejo):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

O html da tabela é parecido com isso:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead></table>
```

Gostaria de adicionar um 'p' no final da tabela com este valor total. Mas não sei como criar isto. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Quando você diz 'p' se refere a tag de parágrafo no HTML?

Comment: Adicionar onde? E o que seria esse 'p'?

Comment: Você quer um total de salario?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

Você pode capturar os dados retornados no ajax e fazer a manipulação deste fora do dataTable.

Pelo que entendi você quer criar um paragrafo depois da tabela contendo o valor, certo?

Tente isso:

```
table.on( 'xhr', function () {
    var json = table.ajax.json();
    console.log(json);
} );
```

Pelo seu exemplo do JSON ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
table.on( 'xhr', function () {
    var json = table.ajax.json();
    document.getElementById('meuParagrafo').innerText = json.valorTotal;
} );
```